# Multiple RelativeLayout inside LinearLayout display error

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a MoodTracker application who store the daily mood into prefs every 24H and show a History of last 7 days mood.
My problem is the following:
My History layout has 7 Relative layouts (one for each day) inside a LinearLayout.
Preview is perfect, one upside another. But when I run the application, 
I can only see 4/7 layouts, each one is way bigger than the expected...
this is my code :
XML : https://github.com/matteovaccari/MoodTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_mood_history.xml
java: https://github.com/matteovaccari/MoodTracker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/matt/android/moodtracker_v2/controllers/MoodHistoryActivity.java
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your RelativeLayouts:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

You should set layout_height="0" if you're using a layout_weight and you want the 7 RelativeLayouts to take up equal space:

```
android:layout_height="0"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In each RelativeLayout fo the following chages:

1. change 'android: layout_height' in each to 0
2. Add 'layout_weight' attribute and set its value as 1

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `android:layout_weight` or fixed size on your views  - it may work for small layouts like this but in big layouts, it may affect your screen performance, When using fixed size on a view it is not responsive to all screen sizes.
 you better use [constraintlayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to get a nice looking screen that is responsive to all of the devices:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Fragments.MenusDesign.BookMenu.BookMenu">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_text_seven"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_five"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_six"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_six"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_five"
    tools:text="string/day_7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_btn_seven"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline11"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_four"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_four"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_text_six"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_seven"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_five"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_five"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_seven"
    tools:text="string/day_6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_btn_six"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_three"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_three"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_text_five"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_four"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_four"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_four"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_four"
    tools:text="string/day_5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_btn_five"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="7"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_seven"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_seven"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline11" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_text_four"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_six"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_three"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_three"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_six"
    tools:text="string/day_4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_btn_four"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_six"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_six"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline9" />" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_text_three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_three"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_two"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_two"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activity_historic_btn_three"
    tools:text="string/day_3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_btn_three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_text_two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_one"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_historic_text_one"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
    tools:text="string/day_2"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/activity_historic_text_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline12"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    tools:text="string/day_1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline12"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.142" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.28" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.42" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.57" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.714" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.857" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```